# why does the compiler complain about missing ctor of WebSocketHandler?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to use websocket in my project.
to do so, I installed the package Microsoft Asp.Net SignalR, which consists of WebSocketHandler abstract class.
i defined a class inheriting WebSocketHandler, but then the compiler complains:
'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments'.
It seems wierd to me, because the definitioin of WebSocketHandler ctor gets a nullable value, which means the ctor could get no parameter,
the definition looks like this:
 protected WebSocketHandler(int? maxIncomingMessageSize);

can anybody tell me what the problem is?
thanks.

Comment: a `nullable parameter` is not the same as `no parameter`. just define a constructor with no parameters and pass null to the other ctor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`protected` member is accessible by derived class instances and there's nothing special about it. Nothing special in the class itself, either @ [WebSocketHandler.cs](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core/Owin/WebSockets/WebSocketHandler.cs).

It just mens you need to pass in a nullable type, it does not mean it can't get any arguments.

```
int? maxIncomingMessageSize = 0;
var socket = new WebSocketHandler(maxIncomingMessageSize);
```

---

In your derived class you could/should define a "constructor that takes 0 arguments".

```
public class MyHandler : WebSocketHandler
{
    // not mandatory
    public MyHandler()
      :this(null) 
    {}

    // mandatory
    public MyHandler(int? maxIncomingMessageSize)
      :base(maxIncomingMessageSize) 
    {}
}
```

Comment: thank you all for trying to help me.. still I don't understand why the compiler complains: 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.WebSockets.WebSocketHandler' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments'. indeed I can't change WebSocketHandler class and add a ctor that takes 0 args. what should I do to correct this error?

Comment: Edited my answer, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

> It seems wierd to me, because the definitioin of WebSocketHandler ctor gets a nullable value, which means the ctor could get no parameter

No, it doesn't. There's a big difference between receiving a `null` value for a nullable type, and not receiving a value at all.

If the parameter were optional, that would be a different matter - but it's not. You *have* to supply an argument convertible to `int?` in the call. If you want to provide the null value for `int?`, do so:

```
var handler = new WebSocketHandler(null);
```

Or if you want to avoid accidentally using any other single-parameter constructor definitions which may be applicable with a `null` literal as the argument, you could use:

```
var handler = new WebSocketHandler((int?) null);
```

Or:

```
var handler = new WebSocketHandler(default(int?));
```